# How to get image url string from j["data"] in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following snippet of code that creates json data (?dictionary?). I can't figure out how to get the avatarUrl string

```py
   def __init__(self, character_id):
        self.character_id = character_id
        self.character_data = self.get_character_data()
        print(self.character_data["id"])
        
    def update(self):
        self.character_data = self.get_character_data()
        
    def get_character_data(self):
        req = requests.get(f"https://character-service.dndbeyond.com/character/v5/character/{self.character_id}")
        #print("hello")
        if req.status_code != 200:
            return None
        try:
            j = req.json()
            if not "success" in j or not "data" in j:
                return None
            return j["data"]

        except ValueError:
            return None
```

The resulting data looks like this. I'm trying to catch the url for `{'avatarUrl': 'https://www.dndbeyond.com/avatars/21222/111/637708177497566513.jpeg'}`, so I can open the image.

> Press CTRL+C to quit
> {'id': 108291017, 'userId': 118256620, 'username': 'sethirya', 'isAssignedToPlayer': True, 'readonlyUrl': 'https://dndbeyond.com/characters/108291017', 'decorations': **{'avatarUrl': 'https://www.dndbeyond.com/avatars/21222/111/637708177497566513.jpeg?**width=150&height=150&fit=crop&quality=95&auto=webp', 'frameAvatarUrl': 'https://www.dndbeyond.com/avatars/7169/957/637042612736861450.png', 'backdropAvatarUrl': 'frameAvatarDecorationKey': '558', 'frameAvatarId': 7169957, 'backdropAvatarDecorationKey': '407', 'backdropAvatarId': 61586, 'smallBackdropAvatarDecorationKey': '61587', 'smallBackdropAvatarId': 61587, 'largeBackdropAvatarDecorationKey': '61588', 'largeBackdropAvatarId': 61588, 'thumbnailBackdropAvatarDecorationKey': '61589', 'thumbnailBackdropAvatarId': 61589, 'themeColor': {'themeColorId': 429, 'themeColor': '#e5623e', 'backgroundColor': '#FEFEFE', 'name': 'Barbarian Fire', 'raceId': None, 'subRaceId': None, 'classId': 9, 'tags': ['Class Themes'], 'decorationKey': '429'}}, 'name': 'Raine', 'socialName': None, 'gender': 'Female/Non-binary', 'faith': '', 'age': 29, 'hair': '', 'eyes': 'gr

I tried just using the print function to obtain the desired item. I can print many other items, but I need help with this.

Comment: What's wrong with  `j["data"]["decorations"]["avatarUrl"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j = req.json()` makes `j` a dictionary with the response. Part of the response can be contained in nested dictionaries.

Judging by the example in your post, your desired parameter is in nested dictionary by the name `decorations`, so you can get it like this:

```
self.character_data.get("decorations", {}).get("avatarUrl", "")
```

This will give you an url:

```
https://www.dndbeyond.com/avatars/21222/111/637708177497566513.jpeg?width=150&height=150&fit=crop&quality=95&auto=webp
```

which leads to a cute dragon pic.

P.S. I use `get` instead of `dict[key]` syntax to protect the code from failing if is `decorations` not in the response or `avatarUrl` is not in the `decorations` dictionary. It falls back on a default value if dictionary key is not present. You can change that as suits you better.

```
self.character_data["decorations"]["avatarUrl"]
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I had just figured out the ["decorations"] part, but it was returning all instances if avatarUrl.  Your info will get me the rest of the way.  And yes, one of my D&D players character avatar.

Comment: where can I read more about working with the formatting in your string.  I've apparently been using the wrong questions in my searches.
get("decorations", {}).get("avatarUrl", "")